# Questions about animations in Processing

Tags: animation, processing

How do I make it so that only one part of a program executes once?

- I have an animation that when the mouse is pressed the background is changed. However, I only want this to happen once.

How do I make it so that only one specific shape has a `stroke(border)`?

- Ex: if I have three circles, how do I make it so that only one has a border?

I tried putting the stroke where I wanted it and [`noStroke();`](https://processing.org/reference/noStroke_.html) at the end but It didn't work.

Answer (score 0):

For the animation, a simple way to achieve this would be to have a boolean e.g playedAnimation. By default, the variable is false and inside draw() when mousePressed is true, we can check if playedAnimation is false. If it is false, play the animation then make it true. Otherwise, do not play the animation.

```
boolean playedAnimation = false;

public void draw()
{
    if (mousePressed && !playedAnimation)
    {
        playAnimation();
        
        playedAnimation = true;
    }
}
```

As for the circles, (assuming you use the P2D renderer), all you have to do is:

Before each circle with a visible stroke, do `strokeWeight(weight); // weight greater than 0`

And for the circle/s you don't want to have a stroke, do `strokeWeight(0);`

```
translate(width / 2f, height / 2f);

strokeWeight(1);
circle(-100, 0, 50);
circle(0, 0, 50);

strokeWeight(0);
circle(100, 0, 50);
```

I tried this with the default render JAVA2D, and it has some strange results.
However, by using transparency you can still achieve this if you want to use the JAVA2D renderer.

```
translate(width / 2f, height / 2f);

stroke(0, 255); // black stroke, full opacity
circle(-100, 0, 50);
circle(0, 0, 50);

stroke(0, 0); // black stroke but zero alpha (invisible)
circle(100, 0, 50);
```